# How to ensure connection closing, when I'm having multiple connections declared in one function?

Tags: python, exception, connection, psycopg2

I have to declare multiple connections in my function and I'm using finally block to ensure they are all closed in case of any exception showing up. Yet, I'm in a quandary with the case when exception occurs during one of the connections being established. I'm aware that closing connections in order they were declared will ensure that even if one of the connections established without problems it will be closed, for sure.

```py
def some_func(x_connect_params,y_connect_params):
    try:
        x_conn = psycopg2.connect(**x_connect_params)
        x_cur = x_conn.cursor()
        y_conn = psycopg2.connect(**y_connect_params)
        y_cur = y_conn.cursor()
        # SOME CODE THAT USES CONNECTIONS
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    finally:
        x_cur.close()
        x_conn.close()
        y_cur.close()
        y_conn.close()
```

Yet I'm wandering is there a way to ensure closing connection AND being able to avoid having an UnboundLocalError in the finally block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what context managers are for, ensuring the releasing of a resource

However psycopg2 context managers don't close the connection, so you can write your own

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

import psycopg2

@contextmanager
def get_connection(connection_param):
    con = psycopg2.connect(**connection_param)
    try:
        yield con
    finally:
        con.close()

@contextmanager
def get_cursor(connection):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    try:
        yield cur
    finally:
        cur.close()


def some_func(x_connect_params,y_connect_params):
    with get_connection(x_connect_params) as x_conn, get_connection(y_connect_params) as y_conn:
        with get_cursor(x_conn) as x_cur, get_cursor(y_conn) as y_cur:
        # SOME CODE THAT USES CONNECTIONS
```

Edit: link to psycopg2 context managers
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/3eecf34beaa0fa2deea9f22baf3b657db412a404/doc/src/usage.rst#with-statement

Comment: Thanks, that helped!